# Could you please identify this wtb cantilever/roller cam brake

Tags: brakes

I've had some issues identifying this brake, and while I do know its wtb and circa late 1980s-early 1990s thats it. Any information would be appreciated. To clarify the parts were not original to the bike frame, as its a 1993 diamondback arrival.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Its an interesting place to put the rear brake, down under the chainstays.  Just being near the chain seems to attract dirt and dust, neither are good for braking.

Comment: @criggie I had similar brakes to these on the rear of a mountainbike many years ago. The idea being (at the time) that the seat stays weren't strong enough for the brakes. They were a real pain to adjust.

Answer (score 2):

Those brake boosters are definetely by WTB, you can see a logo on third photo. I'd gues that whole assembly is by WTB too, at least google images return very similar results ([this post](http://forums.mtbr.com/vintage-retro-classic/lets-see-those-rare-parts-2382-2.html#post6086785) especially, scroll down a bit for a picture).

Comment: Just noticed that title includes WTB in it. Not much to identify here, eh?